# Burninate the [statement] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Some people seem to think that the tag line should read like a sentence:

[mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)[sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)[statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statement)
However the tag [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statement) does not add any info to the question and searching for it lists a mismatch of questions about [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and language features; mostly [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement).

Because the [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statement) tag groups so many different concepts together it really overshoots the purpose of a tag.
It is most often used as an add-on for the [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) or [tag:insert_language_statement_tag_here] tags (in which cases it is superfluous).

As a tag on its own it really does not explain anything; case in point:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764820/what-does-this-number-in-the-statement-mean
[call return inside GCC compound statement expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825943/call-return-inside-gcc-compound-statement-expressions)

Comment: I agree with your edit of the statement tag

Comment: That's for sure a tag benefiting from the bulk-removal.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of questions with both [tag:statement] *and* something like [tag:if-statement]. Is there a feature to remove the [tag:statement] tag from all questions with another tag that also contains *statement*? That would leave the rest for manual editing.

Comment: @Yogu, yes, an SQL UPDATE **statement** :)

Comment: burn with fire.

Comment: This seems reasonable; it is much like the recent suggestion to burninate the `run` tag. It will require editing the following questions which only have the statement tag, which would otherwise end up with no tags: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/190449/246626/questions-with-only-the-statement-tag

Comment: Related -- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289700/burninate-the-statements-tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done.

[image: Burned]

Please [care for the widows and orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/untagged).