# This tag should be [sentence]d to burnination

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentence) tag doesn't seem to bring much to the site. It has 102 questions which are, admittedly, primarily about *sentences*, but I think it's unlikely that there would be any sentence specialists, and I doubt that even a majority of good questions about sentences would even bother using the tag.

Furthermore, I learned about this tag via a question in which the asker misused it in an attempt to refer to a SQL *statement*. So it just doesn't seem overly useful.

I don't think [sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentence) is any more useful than [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statement), which has [already been burninated.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253507/burninate-the-statement-tag)

Following [when to burninate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268199/when-to-burninate/268202#268202):

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

I'd say it's unambiguous, sure, except in the aforementioned case of misuse, although I really don't think it adds anything to the post.

- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No more than *any other topic.* You can write code about sentences, and you can use sentences in code, but it certainly doesn't play the same role as, say, [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or anything of that nature. It is no more relevant than [guitar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guitar) would be to someone writing an Apple Garage Band equivalent.

- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

"Meaningful," no. As I said, it's unlikely that anyone will actively track any questions that have to do with sentences in order to answer questions about, as many of them seem to be, reversing the words in a sentence.

- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

It appears that there's a pretty consistent following in the tag that questions are, in fact, about sentences in the linguistic sense, so I might have to give it this one.

Comment: Actually [tag:sentence] sounds a lot less useful than [tag:guitar] -- the latter might be good for questions about interfacing guitars via MIDI or other digital interfaces, a topic where there truly could be subject-matter experts.

Comment: @BenVoigt true, I hadn't thought of that. I picked it as a random example, but I guess it wasn't a particularly good one.

Comment: The tag should be [sentence]d to burnination.

Comment: I note also the existence of the tag [words], defined as " a single distinct meaningful element of a data" but used as often as not for the linguistic construct which makes up a [sentence].