# Burninate the [statements] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Around this time last year, it looks like [we burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253507/burninate-the-statement-tag) [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statement) in fairly short order. However, [statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statements) is still hanging around.

They probably should have been synonyms, so hopefully the burnination reasons are shared, however:

- This seems like a meta tag

  - Looking through the front page, the tag often appears with a language and/or a  specific type of statement (such as [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement), which at least refers to a particular thing).
  - Even [questions focused on statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390812/are-any-languages-strictly-statement-oriented) don't benefit much from this tag.
- There are 215 questions (80 also with [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement), 48 with no answer).
- The tag wiki is a few sentences from the wikipedia article.

Is this a tag we can safely get rid of?

Answer (score 1):

There are 400 questions now with 8 people watching it.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Maybe.

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

No. Most of the time language tag covers it.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

It is certainly a meta tag. It is used with combination of [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement). Most of the time it means nothing particular on its own and the same word is used in the title or body of the question.

- If it is tagged with [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements) or [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional) 34/400 questions (8.5%) then we can replace it with just [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements)
- If it is tagged with [if-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statements) 146/400 questions (36.5%) then we can replace it with just [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement)
- If it is about [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatements%5D+prepared) 42/400 questions (10.5%) then we can replace it with [prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prepared-statement)
- If it is tagged with [switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-statement) 5/400 questions (~1%) then we can replace it with just [switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch-statement)
- Other tags can be used where applicable such as [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/break), [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continue), [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) or just leave the language tag on its own